# E- and A-algorithms for finite arithmetic prime progressions and other sets

Tags: nt.number-theory, algorithms, prime-numbers

*(EDIT from scratch).*

Let $\ \mathbf a := (a_1\ \ldots\ a_n)\ $ be an increasing non-constant arithmetic progression of odd positive numbers. The **goal** here is to resolve efficiently one of the two situations:

- **every** term $\ a_k\ $ of the progression is a Fermat pseudo-prime;
- **there exists** at least one Fermat pseudo-prime among the terms of the progression.

By *efficiency* it is meant to do better than by working with each term separately. And one can claim extra credit by providing formal algorithmic complexity analysis (there would be more than one way to do it, they don't even have to be equivalent).

I feel that a chance for obtaining an efficient algorithm is high. And all mathematicians and hobbyists know what this means: there were arithmetic progressions which you were not able to decide, and suddenly there are some that you can (which always feels good).

---

> A natural number $\ p\ $ is a Fermat pseudo-prime $\ \Leftarrow:\Rightarrow\,\ 2^{p-1}\equiv 1\mod p$.

Similar problems can be stated also for arithmetic progressions of pseudo-primes in different sense (including simply *primes*); and even for different sets, not just arithmetic progressions, of different objects.

Comment: For a particular example all kinds of things are possible. But in general your assumptions do not allow much. Suppose $t(x)=\frac{1}{2^x}$ for $x$ even and $2^x$ for $x$ odd. It turns out that $P$ only has odd members but you don't know that. $F=\{{\{{2j,2j+1\}}\mid j \in \mathbb{N}\}}.$

Comment: All this is really irrelevant to the problem. I have added an end-remark to my Question in its text.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: "I'd like to know about the algorithms which I am about to describe below." --about the existing algorithms or the new algorithms which you can provide yourself.

Comment: I think you need a more specific framework. Suppose $t(x)$ is constant. Then it could easily take $\max t(x)$ time just to know anything about $A \cap P$ . In any case, sometimes you might have to test the most expensive thing in an $A$. Give a specific example .

Comment: Thank you for forcing me to state things explicitly which were obvious to the people who saw my question in the past.